# JavaScript does not run the ones below the first code(document.get)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
<section class="blogSingle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="blogSingle-left col-md-8">
        <div id="content3" class="blogSingleContent"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="blogSingle-right col-md-4">
        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p><a href="blogSingle2.html">The last summer days</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking1.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p><a href="blogSingle4.html">A Rare Frog Finds a Mate</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking2.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p>
              <a href="blogSingle3.html"
                >Biological diversity convention manifesto</a
              >
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking1.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p><a href="blogSingle2.html">last summer days</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking2.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p>
              <a href="blogSingle1.html">For a decade romeo lived alone</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```js
const blogSingle1 = [{
  photo: "img/treaking.jpg",
  Topic: "For a decade romeo lived alone",
  Description: `d`
}];
const blogSingle2 = [{
  photo: "img/treaking1.jpg",
  Topic: "The last summer days",
  Description: `c`
}];
const blogSingle3 = [{
  photo: "img/treaking2.jpg",
  Topic: "For a decade romeo lived alone",
  Description: `b`
}];
const blogSingle4 = [{
  photo: "img/treaking.jpg",
  Topic: "For a decade romeo lived alone",
  Description: `a`
}];
const blogSingle5 = [{
  photo: "img/treaking1.jpg",
  Topic: "Protect the planet land and ocean",
  Description: `e`
}];

function blogTemplete1(blogSingle) {
  return `
  <div class ="blogSingle">
  <h3>${blogSingle.Topic}</h3>
  <img src="${blogSingle.photo}" />
  <div class="social-icon-links content-social">
    <div class="social facebook">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f mt-2"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social twitter">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter mt-2"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social instragram">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram mt-2"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social google-plus">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g mt-2"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>${blogSingle.Description}</p>
  </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("content3").innerHTML = `
${blogSingle1.map(blogTemplete1).join("")}
`;
document.getElementById("content4").innerHTML = `
${blogSingle2.map(blogTemplete1).join("")}
`;
document.getElementById("content5").innerHTML = `
${blogSingle3.map(blogTemplete1).join("")}
`;
document.getElementById("content6").innerHTML = `
${blogSingle4.map(blogTemplete1).join("")}
`;
document.getElementById("content7").innerHTML = `
${blogSingle5.map(blogTemplete1).join("")}
`;
```

```css
.blogSingleContent h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 95px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.blogSingleContent img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.content-social {
  padding-top: 3% !important;
  padding-bottom: 2% !important;
}

.blogSingleContent p {
  text-align: justify;
}


/* BlogSingle Left End */


/* BlogSingle Right Start */

.blogSingle-right h3 {
  font-size: 16.3833px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.blogSingle-right {
  padding: 100px 50px;
}

.recent-posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.post-image img {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  left: -65px;
}

.post-info span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: rgb(83, 98, 111);
}
```

```html
<section class="blogSingle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="blogSingle-left col-md-8">
        <div id="content3" class="blogSingleContent"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="blogSingle-right col-md-4">
        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p><a href="blogSingle2.html">The last summer days</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking1.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p><a href="blogSingle4.html">A Rare Frog Finds a Mate</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking2.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p>
              <a href="blogSingle3.html">Biological diversity convention manifesto</a
                  >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="recent-posts">
              <div class="post-image">
                <img src="img/treaking1.jpg" alt="..." />
              </div>
              <div class="post-info pl-3">
                <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
                <p><a href="blogSingle2.html">last summer days</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-posts">
          <div class="post-image">
            <img src="img/treaking2.jpg" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div class="post-info pl-3">
            <span>28 Mar 2020</span>
            <p>
              <a href="blogSingle1.html">For a decade romeo lived alone</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>[The content is shown here][1]
</section>
```

so the content3 will show perfectly in one page but the page with content4 and others wont show .[So the content is not shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huJVR.jpg)However if i put document.getElementById("content4") above document.getElementById("content3"). The content of page which contains content 4 works but the one with content 3 wont work basically form the code the one below the conten3 wont run and if i put another one above it that particaular one will work but others wont.

Comment: you have missing `html` code `content4`... are missing

Comment: It tells you the error right there in the console! I saw it because I pressed the "Run code snippet" button in your snippet. Look into your browser console )press F12, go to console tab) then you'll see it on your own page as well. It is in line `document.getElementById("content4").innerHTML = ` so obviously `content4` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

`content4, content5, content6, content7` seem to be missing in your HTML code.

Comment: The other contents are in other html pages but my problem is that document.getElementById on the top like here is of content3 but the content of other such as content4 and so wont show on the pages however if i put any one of them abover the document.getElementById of content3 only that one will work but others wont. You can see this by clicking in this site which i have hosted https://alpins.netlify.com/. Then go the blog page click the first one its content will show but others wont.

Comment: I checked your provided link and everything seems to be working fine. Looks like you figured the answer yourself, right?

Comment: yeah now i fixed it rather improvised it i made a different js file for every document.getElementById by doing so it is working now. But i still dont know why it did not work when it was all in the same page.